# Repeated capture used in repeated backlinks with regex

Tags: regex

I am successfully capturing successive groups that end with a colon, but I don't know how I might have each of those captures to be repeated in the replace, with backlink references. Here is a sample haystack:

```
body .wpCSS {
font-size:14px;
font-size:1rem;
color:#444;
}

div .vaCSS {
font-size:12px;
font-size:.8rem;
color:#555;
}
```

Here is regex that captures: opening brace through first colon, and then through each colon, and then through closing brace. Non-greedy so that only one section is matched at a time.

```
\{(.*?:)+?(.*?)\}
```

I want the replace operation to insert a space after each colon. I have tried all the backlink references, nested, etc. that I can think, but I can get the backlink reference(s) to only act on the first or the last colon section. I am trying for backlink referencing, on any haystack size, that will insert the space after each colon. Note: I am using Notepad++, and I have the dot set to match new lines, so that is how the dot is handling the new lines.

Answer (score 1):

perl

```
s/([^:]*:)/\1 /g;
```

works for me; inserts a space after each colon.

Only inside curly braces

```
s/([^}:]*:)(?=[^{]*[}])/\1 /g;
```

Comment: Thanks. The matching and replacing needs to be limited to characters between the braces, though. In usage, the colon also appears outside the braces and spaces should not be added in those spots.

Comment: post updated to cater for that.